# How to override logging in dataflow with my logback.xml file?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

We are trying to use our logback.xml that we use in GCP Cloud run which has amazing filtering features.  Our logback.xml contains this for cloud run

```
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
        <layout class="com.orderlyhealth.api.logging.logback.GCPCloudLoggingJSONLayout">
            <pattern>${CONSOLE_PATTERN}</pattern>
        </layout>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

And our GCPCloudLoggingJSONLayout does a great job at setting all the things we need like clientId, customerRequestId, etc. etc. and we can filter across many many microservices on one customer or one customer request.  We lose this in dataflow currently though.  We tried adding logback.xml to src/main/resources and deploying the project seems to use it in the shell like so

```
{"message":"[main][-][:] o.a.b.r.d.DataflowRunner  Template successfully created.\n",
 "logger":"org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner",
"transactionId":null,"socket":null,"clntSocket":null,
"version":null,
"timestamp":{"seconds":1619694798,"nanos":4000000},
"thread":"main",
"severity":"INFO",
"instanceId":null,
"headers":{},
"messageInfo":{"message":"Message short enough.  Displayed top level"}
}
```

thanks for any ideas on modifying dataflow logging.

Currently we see this instead which is not nearly as useful for tracing the customer request through systems

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can change how Dataflow logs to Cloud logging.

Instead, you can change how/what you log and let Dataflow pass them through to cloud logging. See [Logging pipeline messages](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/logging).

Or you can use cloud logging client libraries in your pipeline directly: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [How to override Google DataFlow logging with logback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73656823/how-to-override-google-dataflow-logging-with-logback/74892158#74892158) for the latest version of this answer

I copied the current answer there to make it easier for folks who want to look:
Dataflow relies on using java.util.logging (aka JUL) as the logging backend for SLF4J and adds various bridges ensuring that logs from other libraries are output as well. With this kind of setup, we are limited to adding any additional details to the log message itself only.

This also applies to any runner executing a portable job since the container with the SDK harness has a similar logging configuration. For example Dataflow Runner V2.

To do this we want to create a custom formatter to apply to the root JUL logger. For example:

```
public class CustomFormatter extends SimpleFormatter {
  public String formatMessage(LogRecord record) {
    // implement whatever logic the is needed to add details to the message portion of the log statement
    return super.formatMessage(record);
  }
}
```

And then during start-up of the worker we need to update the root logger to use this formatter. We can achieve this using a `JvmInitializer` and implement the `beforeProcessing` method like so:

```
@AutoService(JvmInitializer.class)
public class LoggerInitializer implements JvmInitializer {
  public void beforeProcessing(PipelineOptions options) {
    LogManager logManager = LogManager.getLogManager();
    Logger rootLogger = logManager.getLogger("");
    for (Handler handler : rootLogger.getHandlers()) {
      handler.setFormatter(new CustomFormatter());
    }
  }
}
```